# Music player is playing only from one folder

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've been having an issue recently with my JavaScript code. It is a music player which changes playlist depending on the time;

2AM-6AM - plays music from audio/early_morning

6AM-11AM - plays music from audio/morning

11AM-7PM - plays music from audio/daytime

7PM-10PM - plays music from audio/primetime

10PM-2AM - plays music from audio/nightclub

Here is the code in question:

```js
// TIME OF DAY
var early_morning, morning, daytime, primetime, nightclub;
early_morning = new Date();
morning = new Date();
daytime = new Date();
primetime = new Date();
nightclub = new Date();
early_morning.setUTCHours(1);
morning.setUTCHours(5);
daytime.setUTCHours(10);
primetime.setUTCHours(18);
nightclub.setUTCHours(21);

// AUDIO PLAYER
var lastSong = null;
var selection = null;
if (early_morning > morning) {
    var playlist = ["audio/early_morning/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/early_morning/adagio.mp3", "audio/early_morning/all_obsessed.mp3", "audio/early_morning/no_saints.mp3", "audio/early_morning/swingin_partay.mp3"];
}
if (morning > daytime) {
    var playlist = ["audio/morning/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/morning/cool_groovings.mp3", "audio/morning/game_on.mp3", "audio/morning/half_pipe.mp3", "audio/morning/hope.mp3", "audio/morning/internationale!.mp3", "audio/morning/move_it.mp3", "audio/morning/muted.mp3", "audio/morning/no_saints.mp3", "audio/morning/swingin_partay.mp3"];
}
if (daytime > primetime) {
    var playlist = ["audio/primetime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/primetime/apocalypse(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/bondicular(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/choir_of_impending_breakbeat.mp3", "audio/primetime/cine2000.mp3", "audio/primetime/kompressor(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore.mp3", "audio/primetime/quest.mp3", "audio/primetime/swingin_partay.mp3", "audio/primetime/the_trap.mp3"];
}
if (primetime > nightclub) {
    var playlist = ["audio/daytime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/daytime/2009_trk7.mp3", "audio/daytime/4mp3", "audio/daytime/connected.mp3", "audio/daytime/funkerama.mp3", "audio/daytime/gritty_groove.mp3", "audio/daytime/internationale!(remix)", "audio/daytime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/daytime/smooth_strings_trip.mp3", "audio/daytime/sunset.mp3", "audio/daytime/swingin_partay.mp3"];
}
if (nightclub > early_morning) {
    var playlist = ["audio/nightclub/adagio.mp3", "audio/nightclub/apocalypse.mp3", "audio/nightclub/dance_9.mp3", "audio/nightclub/internationale!.mp3", "audio/nightclub/nu-soul_village(remix).mp3", "audio/nightclub/obsessive.mp3", "audio/nightclub/universe.mp3"]; 
}
var player = document.getElementById("player"); // Get Audio Element
player.autoplay = true;
player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when song ends

function selectRandom() {
    while (selection == lastSong) { // Repeat until different song is selected
        selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
    }
    lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
    player.src = playlist[selection]; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song

}

selectRandom(); // Select initial song
player.play(); // Start Song
```

The problem is that my website is only playing music from the nightclub folder when at the time of posting this, it should be playing music from the primetime folder.

Is there a problem with my code? If so, how can I fix it?

Thanks,

-S

Comment: Here's the website's GitHub repo: https://github.com/OldDigibox/sky-web-epg

Comment: Here's the website: https://olddigibox.github.io/sky-web-epg/

Comment: You can edit your post and include the links in your question. additionally try to avoid closing remarks like "thanks", or "any help is appreciated!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the following snippet, you will see the conditions that are hit. The way you are setting the time, the only condition that will be true is `nightclub > early_morning` this is because when you are using `setUTCHours` it's basically setting the date and freezing it at that time. Imagine a simpler situation where you aren't using date objects, and you are just using numbers here. Look up how to use a debugger here, and stepping through code to see what the variables are actually evaluating to.

```js
// TIME OF DAY
var early_morning, morning, daytime, primetime, nightclub;
early_morning = new Date();
morning = new Date();
daytime = new Date();
primetime = new Date();
nightclub = new Date();
early_morning.setUTCHours(1);
morning.setUTCHours(5);
daytime.setUTCHours(10);
primetime.setUTCHours(18);
nightclub.setUTCHours(21);

// AUDIO PLAYER
var lastSong = null;
var selection = null;
if (early_morning > morning) {
    console.log('early_morning > morning')
}
if (morning > daytime) {
    console.log('morning > daytime')
}
if (daytime > primetime) {
    console.log('daytime > primetime')
}
if (primetime > nightclub) {
    console.log('primetime > nightclub')
}
if (nightclub > early_morning) {
    console.log('nightclub > early_morning')
}
```

Here's a more straightforward approach would be to check the current time against predefined intervals. This isn't better or worse than your approach, but I just use it to show that for each number input, there should be only one output.

```js
const intervals = {
  2: "early_morning",
  3: "early_morning",
  4: "early_morning",
  5: "early_morning",
  6: "early_morning",
  7: "morning",
  8: "morning",
  9: "morning",
  10: "morning",
  11: "morning",
  12: "daytime",
  13: "daytime",
  14: "daytime",
  15: "daytime",
  16: "daytime",
  17: "daytime",
  18: "daytime",
  19: "daytime",
  20: "primetime",
  21: "primetime",
  22: "primetime",
  23: "nightclub",
  0: "nightclub",
  1: "nightclub",
  2: "nightclub",
}

const hour = new Date().getHours()
console.log(intervals[hour]);
```

```js
const playlist = [{
    name: 'earlyMorning',
    times: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    songs: ["audio/morning/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/morning/cool_groovings.mp3", "audio/morning/game_on.mp3", "audio/morning/half_pipe.mp3", "audio/morning/hope.mp3", "audio/morning/internationale!.mp3", "audio/morning/move_it.mp3", "audio/morning/muted.mp3", "audio/morning/no_saints.mp3", "audio/morning/swingin_partay.mp3"]
  },
  {
    name: 'morning',
    times: [7, 8, 9],
    songs: ["audio/daytime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/daytime/2009_trk7.mp3", "audio/daytime/4mp3", "audio/daytime/connected.mp3", "audio/daytime/funkerama.mp3", "audio/daytime/gritty_groove.mp3", "audio/daytime/internationale!(remix)", "audio/daytime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/daytime/smooth_strings_trip.mp3", "audio/daytime/sunset.mp3", "audio/daytime/swingin_partay.mp3"]
  },
  {
    name: 'daytime',
    times: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    songs: ["audio/primetime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/primetime/apocalypse(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/bondicular(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/choir_of_impending_breakbeat.mp3", "audio/primetime/cine2000.mp3", "audio/primetime/kompressor(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore.mp3", "audio/primetime/quest.mp3", "audio/primetime/swingin_partay.mp3", "audio/primetime/the_trap.mp3"]
  },
  {
    name: 'primetime',
    times: [20, 21, 22],
    songs: ["audio/daytime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/daytime/2009_trk7.mp3", "audio/daytime/4mp3", "audio/daytime/connected.mp3", "audio/daytime/funkerama.mp3", "audio/daytime/gritty_groove.mp3", "audio/daytime/internationale!(remix)", "audio/daytime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/daytime/smooth_strings_trip.mp3", "audio/daytime/sunset.mp3", "audio/daytime/swingin_partay.mp3"]
  },
  {
    name: 'nightclub',
    times: [23, 0, 1, 2],
    songs: ["audio/nightclub/adagio.mp3", "audio/nightclub/apocalypse.mp3", "audio/nightclub/dance_9.mp3", "audio/nightclub/internationale!.mp3", "audio/nightclub/nu-soul_village(remix).mp3", "audio/nightclub/obsessive.mp3", "audio/nightclub/universe.mp3"]
  }
]

let nowPlaying = null;
// const player = document.getElementById("player"); // Get Audio Element
// player.autoplay = true;
// player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when song ends

function selectRandom() {
  // destructure object because all we want is the song array
  const { songs } = playlist.find(list => list.times.includes(new Date().getHours()));
  // remove the currently playing song, or nothing if null
  const filteredSongs = songs.filter(song => song != nowPlaying);
  // pick a random song out of the remaining songs
  const selection =  filteredSongs[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredSongs.length)]
  lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
  // player.src = selection; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song
  console.log(`Now playing ${selection}`);
}

selectRandom(); // Select initial song
//player.play(); // Start Song
```

Comment: How can I make these change the song playlist?

Comment: I have added a snippet of how I would approach the problem. I commented out the code associated with the player because it does not exist here. @barney

Comment: Thanks for this! I will credit you when I publish the changes.

Comment: The "Now playing" message appears in the console, but the audio isn't playing. Is there anything I should put in index.html?

Comment: @barney the console log is just to show you what is going on. the line `player.src = selection` just needs to be un commented. I appreciate you thinking of crediting me, but you should just try to understand it yourself and then implement it. It's best to know what is going on because then next time you can solve the problem if it changes slightly. Not trying to be preachy, just want you to succeed!

Comment: After playing the song the JS doesn't select another one, how do I fix this?

Comment: have you uncommented all of the lines @barney

Comment: I don't know. If you want to make another question I will look at it, though. @barney